# Why a smiley is displayed instead of a username?

Tags: c++

Why a smiley is displayed instead of a username?

Changing console properties did not help...

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string UserName() {
    TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
    std::string UserName1;
    UserName1 = GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &size);
    std::cout << UserName1 << std::endl;
    return UserName1;
}
int main()
{
    UserName();
}
```

Conclusion: ☺

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). StackOverflow is not a debug-my-program service.

Comment: Is `GetUserName` returning a `std::string`?

Comment: Is GetUserName returning a smiley?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea) of that function. The signature is

```
BOOL GetUserNameA(
  LPSTR   lpBuffer,
  LPDWORD pcbBuffer
);
```

The function's return value is a `BOOL`, which is **non-zero** if the function succeeded. It *does not* return a string. The `username` buffer you pass to the `lpBuffer` parameter will contain the username:

```
std::string UserName() {
    char username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
    std::string UserName1;
    if (GetUserNameA(username, &size))
        UserName1.assign(username, size-1);
    std::cout << UserName1 << std::endl;
    return UserName1;
}
```

As to why it displays a smiley, the reason is quite simple: the function happens to return `TRUE`, which is a `1` on your platform. A `BOOL` is an `int`, and this can be coerced to a `char`. Thus, the compiler calls the `operator=(char)` method on your `std::string`, writing `char` 0x01 to the `std::string` and setting its length to 1:

> The string value is set to a single copy of this character (the string length becomes 1).

To recap, you're assigning character code 0x01 to your `std::string`. I assume you're running your code in a Windows Command Prompt, which uses an encoding derived from DOS' codepage 437. Here is its character map:

[image: character map]

The upper left corner is code 0. What do you see right next to it? (tip: after 0 comes 1).

P.S.: On Windows, you can type any character of CP437 by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing the character code. <kbd>Alt + 1</kbd> will give you the smiley you got by running your program.

Comment: And what do I need to do to get the desired option?

Comment: Your code is almost completely correct. The problem is described in the second paragraph of my answer. Try to fiddle with your function, and with the `cout` line.

Comment: @ЛевСолодко You created variables to store the user name and the size of the user name, wrote code to populate them with the correct values, and then, for some reason, outputted something else entirely.